# Problema con URLField y modelo al cargar una imagen

Tags: django, django-models

introducir el código aquí No puedo cargar una imagen con URLFiel del panel admin de django. Lo que me aparece en el html es la direccion de imagen escrita, por lo tanto alguna conexion hay. no consigo cargar una imagen copiando la url de google de una imageen

***modelo.py***

```
    titulo=models.CharField("Titulo",max_length=30,blank=False,null=False)
    slug=models.CharField("Slug",max_length=30,blank=False,null=False)
    descripcion=models.CharField(max_length=110,blank=False,null=False)
    contenido=RichTextField(default="contenido")
    imagen=models.URLField(max_length=255,blank=False,null=False)
    estado=models.BooleanField("Publicado/No",default=True)
    fecha_creacion=models.DateField("Fecha Creacion",auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name= "Post"
        verbose_name_plural ="Post"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
***views.py***

def detallePost(request,slug):
    post=Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request,"post.html",{"detalle_post":post})
```

Comment: No a de ser que necesitas un campo [`ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)?

Comment: Estoy pensando en usar esto que me dices, esque estoy en un curso y a el le funciona y a mi no,igual es por tener diferente plantilla html. usare ImageField deberia funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la url apunta a una imagen en el template esto debe de funcionar.

```
<img src="{{detalle_post.imagen}}" alt="">
```

Comment: Esto ha funcionado para mi, el mentor del curso le funcionaba como yo lo tenia. gracias